# Bochner integral: Why is $\lvert\lvert \int \rvert\rvert = 1$

Tags: integration, banach-spaces

In lecture came the following remark:

> Let $(\Omega, \mu)$ be a finite measure space and let $X$ be a Banach space. We denote the space of all Bochner-integrable functions $\Omega \rightarrow X$ by $L^1(\Omega,X)$ and equip it with the norm $\lvert \lvert f \rvert \rvert_{L^1(\Omega,X)} := \int \lvert\lvert f \rvert\rvert_X$. If $\mu$ is non-trivial, then $\lvert\lvert \int \rvert\rvert = 1$.

I already know that $\int$ is linear and bounded, so by definition

$$\bigg\lvert\bigg\lvert \int \bigg\rvert\bigg\rvert = sup_{\lvert\lvert f \rvert\rvert =1} \bigg\lvert\bigg\lvert \int f d\mu \bigg\rvert\bigg\rvert$$

, but I do not see how to continue from here. Could you please give me a hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that
$$\left\|\int f d \mu\right\| \le \int \|f\|.$$
Therefore
$$\left\|\int \right\| \le 1,$$
then take $f$ a suitable constant function and try to show that, for such an $f$,
$$\left\|\int f d\mu\right\| = 1.$$

Comment: and the existence of a constant $f$ that maximizes the operator norm is guaranteed by finiteness of the measure.